# I have a question about 40K

Tags: warhammer-40k

For a couple of weeks I have been thinking about starting to play Warhammer 40k and as a noob in this game I have a few questions I could use an answer to:

1. Is it possible for a game to be played with three of more armies?
2. And what army would be best suited for a starter in terms of price, painting.

Comment: I would recommend splitting this into two separate questions: "Can 40k be played with 3+ armies? If so, how?", and "What 40k armies are suitable for getting started?". I'm concerned the latter may be a bit opinion-based, but maybe some people could come up with solid, objective answers. Maybe a better question would be, "Where can I find good starter 40k armies?" - perhaps someone could point you to a site that specializes in 40k lists.

Comment: Also, please consider choosing more descriptive titles for your question - indicating what game it is about is better done by adding the appropriate tag.

Answer (score 1):

It's worth noting that a new edition of 40k is dropping on the 17th, and the game is going to have many HUGE changes. Also, you might find you get a better response on sites like reddit (I'd recommend [/r/warhammer40k/](http://www.reddit.com/r/warhammer40k/) ) or  dedicated 40k forums like [Dakkadakka](http://www.dakkadakka.com) where you can get tailored opinions.

Regardless the best army to start with is one that appeals to you (fluff, playstyle, paintscheme, models depending on YOUR preference) ... If you like the armies in the starter box a great (economic) way to start is to split one w/ a friend but if you don't like the starter armies there are plenty of other options.

Ultimately how you get started is an intensely personal decision.